does setting spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto to create-drop within a Singleton Testcontainer dirties my ApplicationContext?
I have the following Singleton Container as described in Testcontainers Lifecycle
public abstract class AbstractPostgresIT {
  static PostgreSQLContainer<?> POSTGRES_CONTAINER =
      new PostgreSQLContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse("postgres:16")).withDatabaseName("ems")
          .withUsername("username").withPassword("password");

  static {
    POSTGRES_CONTAINER.start();
  }

  @DynamicPropertySource
  public static void dynamicPropertySource(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
    registry.add("spring.datasource.url", POSTGRES_CONTAINER::getJdbcUrl);
    registry.add("spring.datasource.username", POSTGRES_CONTAINER::getUsername);
    registry.add("spring.datasource.password", POSTGRES_CONTAINER::getPassword);
    registry.add("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto", () -> "create-drop");
  }
}

I have two classes extending AbstractPostgresIT (one @DataJpaTest and one @SpringBootTest). Sometimes (till now its random and I havn't figured out a pattern jet) when running mvn clean verify I get an error as
HikariPool-2 - Failed to validate connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@4ec6f11d (This connection has been closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.

I wonder and try to understand if this approach dirties my context by confusing the HikariPool with the Singleton Container. Then I could add @DirtiesContext to AbstractPostgresIT with good conscience. But I'm not an experienced Spring user so I would like to understand in detail whats happening here, especially since it happens randomly. Does setting spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto to create-drop dirties my ApplicationContext? If yes, why? If not, are there other issues I might not be aware of?
EDIT: I can confirm that the second IT fails if there "only" is a HikariPool-2 but works if there is a HikariPool-3. So an updated question: Can I force the creation of a new HikariPool by using @DirtiesContext and is it good practice to do so?
EDIT2: I prepared the reproducible test suite: github repo

I assume every number in HikariPool-n will represent a new Spring Context being created. Using @DirtiesContext will lead to the creation of additional Spring Contexts, but applying this here without clear understanding of the why will work around the symptoms, without solving for the root cause and I highly advocate against it. Ideally you reuse the same context across all tests, unless you have a strong reason to clearly recreate a context.

The problem is your tests. A lot of tests create a new application context (basically a new application) due to the difference in configuration. However as your container is a shared static container the schema doesn't get refreshed and you end up with data from the previous test being in. Which probably influence your other tests. Either re-use the same context or fix your tests to cleanup after themselves or make the container on a per-test basis instead of static so it gets refreshed. I would suggest using the Spring BOot testcontainer support to make this easier.

okay so spring caches the context, but e.g. using DynamicPropertySource, WebMvcTest or DataJpaTest mess up with this cache and make that a new cache is created which can't be reused?

It is hard to say what is happening there without knowing the rest of your test suite (a minimal reproducer project would definitely help), but I would not just add a @DirtiesContext, without consciously knowing, what is dirtying your context. It looks like something is stopping or restarting the container, might this happen?

Does setting spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto to create-drop dirties my ApplicationContext?

No.
In general, integrating the container as a @Bean with @ServiceConnection might help with aligning more with the overall Spring context (see Spring Boot docs).
Edit:
After checking the reproducer, I see that
HikariPool-2 - Failed to validate connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@4ec6f11d (This connection has been closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value. is just logged as a warning,  during Spring Context shutdown. You can ignore this, it is not an issue at all and it won't make the tests fail.

I just edited the question as I found out another pattern when the tests fail and when they don't

No, the spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop setting does not dirty your Spring context.
It only  instructs Hibernate to drop and recreate the database schema at the start and end of the session.
And yes , try Adding @DirtiesContext to your abstract test class. it  can help ensure that the Spring context is refreshed between tests.
You can use classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS so that the application context will be marked as dirty and will be closed and removed from the cache after all the tests in the test class have run

But what exactly is dirtiing my context?

ditying the context means making changes that that alter the state of the application context in such a way that it could affect other tests if they share the same context.
exmpl : Changing environment properties, Adding, removing, or modifying beans or their properties, Changing the state of a shared database . . .

check this : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-dirtiescontext

Where do I alter the state of the application?
